# Open url with post method in background in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend

I want to open a (https://example.com/core/login) with post method when user tried to login for send login datas to a php file with post method in background of login page and get result with javascript.
This php file result is in json format and I want to tell to javascript if the 'result' is 'ok' in : `{'result':'ok','userid':'65363546'}` redirect user to dashboard else show a sample error.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. A mere “I want” is not considered an appropriate question here, you need to show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fetch api or axios plugin to make a post request and check if the response result equals `'ok'`. On true condition you can use `window.location.href = '/path/to/dashboard'` on false you can do whatever to generate the error message.

```js
const loginData = {
    "email": "x@y.z",
    "password": "xyz@password"
};

const headers = {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(loginData)
}

fetch('https://example.com/core/login', headers).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.result == 'ok') {
        window.location.href = "/path/to/dashboard";
    } else {
        alert("Error: show a descriptive error");
    }
  });
```